# mySql database connecting to wrong server

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to setup a Sql database, but I can't get it to connect in php. here's what my code looks like:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("my_sql_here.net","root",'my_password_here');
print $conn;
mysql_select_db("my_database",$conn);

$created = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `inventory`);
if(!$created) {
print "error: ";
print mysql_error();
}
print json_encode($created);
mysql_close($conn);
```

When I run this code, I get:

> error: Access denied for user 'dom710'@'localhost' (using password: NO)false

Why is it tryng to connect to localhost? and why is trying to use root as the password?
I am super confused.

Comment: You should consider switching from MySQL as it has been [officially](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) deprecated. Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) **with** [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). I would suggest rewriting it in one of the above suggested options and forget all about MySQL, as you are a beginner it would be best to start out with the best practices rather than learning the old outdated practices.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem as stated. Is this script being included in something else?

Comment: Oh, you should have a error in your syntax as you are missing a `"` (double quote) in your query.

Comment: So both mqsqli and pdo give me a error 500. I suspect that it is because they are not installed. How would I go about installing them in cpanel?

Comment: MySQLi or PDO don't have to be "installed". Just read on how to use it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using PDO to make a connection:

```
// Establish a connection
$host = 'my_sql_here.net';
$name = 'my_database';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'my_password_here';

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=$name;host=$host;charset=utf8";
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

// Perform your query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `inventory`';
$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$resultSet = $statement->fetchAll();

// Do stuff with your $resultSet
```

Answer (score 0):

You have configured safe mode. This is why it tries to connect to localhost.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-function.mysql-connect.html
`$server` "In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored and value 'localhost:3306' is always used."
`$username` "In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored and the name of the user that owns the server process is used."

And as someone stated in comments you shouldn't use this function because it's deprecated.

Comment: How do I tell it not to start in safe mode? Isn't it off by default?

Comment: http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sql.safe-mode default value is 0 but in some linux distributions it might be overrided. Just check your phpinfo() to see if it's on or off